Choosing price selecting from 2 customers
I have to find a price by choosing the correct price out 3 options in a hierarchy
from highest to lowest

if trtype is Quot than choose this price over all from the [price] column
if Alvl is greater than 0 then choose this price.(so if alvl is 6 then choose blvl = 6 and customer = lvlholder and latest date (start_date) for that price.
last if both trtype is blank and Alvl is 0 then choose this price. (for this customer the default customer level is 8, so looking for blvl = 8 and customer = lvlholder)

All the "level prices" from 1-8 are stored in a lvlholder customer but have multiple price records so I need to pull the latest date for those. blvl is the level for the prices 1-8 stored in this lvlholder customer. (not sure why its setup like this but that's how it is).
It's a weird query because I'm choosing one customer ("test") to look at for [trtype] and [alvl] and if [alvl] > 0 or both [trtype] is blank and [alvl] is 0 then I have to choose a price with customer being lvlholder and [alvl] has to match with [blvl] for those.
below is the outcome I would like from the query, when customer is "test"



itemcode
uom
price
start_date
FinalResult




ABC1234
EA
0.00
1/15/2024
29.57


X123456
CT
144.10
5/15/2024
144.10


BR23456
PC
0.00
1/1/2024
15.56


CX23456
PNL
0.00
1/1/2024
15.36



Below is the table and it's data for [sample data][1]
create table pricing(Customer,itemcode,uom,trtype,Alvl,Blvl,price,start_date)as values
 ('test','ABC1234','EA','',6,0,0.0,'5/27/2024'::date)
,('test','X123456','CT','Quot',0,0,144.1,'5/15/2024')-----------
,('test','BR23456','PC','',0,0,0,'4/21/2024')
,('test','CX23456','PNL','',0,0,0,'4/21/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,3,44.9,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,3,44.9,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,5,41.38,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,5,41.38,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,2,34.81,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,5,30.49,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,8,28.39,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,2,49.89,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,2,49.89,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,7,37.24,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,7,37.24,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,4,31.43,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,7,28.97,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,1,62.36,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,1,62.36,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,8,36.5,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,8,36.5,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,1,38.65,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,3,33.05,'1/15/2024')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,6,29.57,'1/15/2024')------------
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,4,42.66,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,4,42.66,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,6,40.13,'07/11/23')
,('lvlholder','ABC1234','EA','',0,6,40.13,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,1,251.68,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,2,201.52,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,3,191.4,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,4,181.72,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,5,176.22,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,6,170.94,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,7,165.88,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','X123456','CT','',0,8,156.63,'01/01/53')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,5,16.23,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,5,16.23,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,8,14.82,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,8,14.82,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,1,23.51,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,1,23.51,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,3,17.99,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,3,17.99,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,4,17.09,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,4,17.09,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,3,18.89,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,4,17.94,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,5,17.04,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,6,16.54,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,7,16.04,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,8,15.56,'01/01/24')--------
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,2,19.99,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,2,19.99,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,7,15.28,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,7,15.28,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,1,24.69,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,2,20.99,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,6,15.75,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','BR23456','PC','',0,6,15.75,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,1,24.38,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,2,19.74,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,2,19.74,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,5,16.03,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,5,16.03,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,7,15.09,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,7,15.09,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,2,20.73,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,3,18.66,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,4,17.72,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,5,16.83,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,6,16.33,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,7,15.84,'01/01/24')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,8,15.36,'01/01/24')------
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,8,14.63,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,8,14.63,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,1,23.22,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,1,23.22,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,3,17.77,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,3,17.77,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,4,16.88,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,4,16.88,'11/30/2023')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,6,15.55,'07/05/23')
,('lvlholder','CX23456','PNL','',0,6,15.55,'11/30/2023')
;

I had to include all the data for these 4 items to show it has to choose the latest date for the ones that involve the first 2 options not being the correct price. There are lots of older prices being stored for each item.
SELECT [itemcode],[uom],[trtype], [alvl],[blvl],[start_date],
  CASE 
    WHEN [trtype] <> '' THEN [price] 
    WHEN  [alvl] > 0 THEN XXXXXX
  ELSE 0 
  END AS LevelResult 
FROM [test].[testtable].[pricing] 
WHERE [start_cust_or_group] ='test'  
   and [RowDeleted] = 0
   and [item_or_pricecode] in ('ABC1234','X123456','BR23456','CX23456')
ORDER BY [start_date] desc

Tried a select where I put XXXXXXX but not sure how to pass the [alvl] to look for matching [blvl] where customer is lvlholder

I created a fiddle to help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/4RlMPiot

What if trtype is not blank or Quot and Alvl is 0 ?

If your ('test','ABC1234', ...) source data row had a 2023-12-31 date instead of 2024-05-27, would you still want the overall latest 2024-01-15 price (38.65) or would you want the most recent prior 2023-11-30 price (62.36)?

I think sub queries within the CASE THEN parts will get the info you want
SELECT p.[itemcode],
       p.[uom],
       p.[trtype], 
       p.[alvl],
       p.[blvl],
       CASE WHEN  p.[alvl]>0  THEN (SELECT top 1 x.start_date FROM pricing x WHERE x.itemcode=p.itemcode AND x.blvl=p.alvl AND customer = 'lvlholder' ORDER BY start_date desc)
       WHEN p.[trtype] = '' THEN (SELECT top 1 x.start_date FROM pricing x WHERE x.itemcode=p.itemcode AND x.blvl=8 AND customer = 'lvlholder' ORDER BY start_date desc)
      ELSE p.[start_date] END as start_date,
  CASE 
  WHEN p.[trtype] = 'Quot' THEN p.[price]
  WHEN p.[alvl]>0  THEN (SELECT top 1 x.price FROM pricing x WHERE x.itemcode=p.itemcode AND x.blvl=p.alvl AND customer = 'lvlholder' ORDER BY start_date desc)
  WHEN p.[trtype] = '' THEN (SELECT top 1 x.price FROM pricing x WHERE x.itemcode=p.itemcode AND x.blvl=8 AND customer = 'lvlholder' ORDER BY start_date desc)
  ELSE 0
  END AS LevelResult ,
  p.price
FROM pricing p
WHERE p.[Customer] ='test'  
   --and [RowDeleted] = 0
   and p.[itemcode] in ('ABC1234','X123456','BR23456','CX23456')
ORDER BY p.[start_date] desc

fiddle



itemcode
uom
trtype
alvl
blvl
start_date
LevelResult
price




ABC1234
EA

6
0
2024-01-15
29.57
0


X123456
CT
Quot
0
0
2024-05-15
144.1
144.1


BR23456
PC

0
0
2024-01-01
15.56
0


CX23456
PNL

0
0
2024-01-01
15.36
0




that worked! I ran into another snag though if the "test" customer doesn't have data for the itemcode it skips it is there a way to force it in the result on the last case where x.level=8. would I just add it in the ELSE spot? thanks!  I tried adding "and p.[alvl]=0" on the last where clause in the cases but it didn't work as expected.

Please provide example data or a fiddle link that demonstrates that scenario.  Do you mean this example with item code XXX ? https://dbfiddle.uk/3T_Hr7fO

no it would be the inverse you would remove an entry for the specific customer in this case "test" so remove say  ,('test','BR23456','PC','',0,0,0,'4/21/2024') in the data. i would like it to still find an entry for the itemcode BR23456 cause the p.[itemcode] in ('ABC1234','X123456','BR23456','CX23456') is still asking for it

@Siege The p.[Customer] ='test' within the WHERE clause would prevent any BR23456 row from being found because no test customer row exist that has itemcode BR23456.

@Siege Yes that would just be another Case WHEN ... THEN subquery as UOM instead of just of p.[uom]. The solution with joins is starting to look more efficient with this type of requirement.  just add UOM to the a and t queries.

is there a way to write a case if an itemcode is missing from the "test" company to look for it at level_ = 8 with customer being 'lvlholder', cause there is a price for every code stored in lvlholder. so say for example the "test" doesn't have BR23456 but it's still there in lvlholder so look for it at level_ 8 pricing

You can use a OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...) pattern to handle price lookups for the second and third cases. With some NULLIF()/COALESCE() trickery, those two lookup cases can be combined.
Since you did not provide a data source for the default customer level, I have just defined a hardcoded value below.
DECLARE @DefaultCustomerLevel INT = 8 -- This should come from a customer table

SELECT
    P.itemcode, P.uom, P.price,
    CASE P.trtype
        WHEN 'Quot' THEN P.start_date
        WHEN '' THEN PLookup.start_date
        END AS start_date,
    CASE P.trtype
        WHEN 'Quot' THEN P.price
        WHEN '' THEN PLookup.price
        END AS FinalResult
FROM pricing P
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM pricing P1
    WHERE P.trtype = ''
    AND P1.customer = 'lvlholder'
    AND P1.itemcode = P.itemcode  -- Maybe
    AND P1.Blvl = COALESCE(NULLIF(P.Alvl, 0),  @DefaultCustomerLevel)
    --AND P1.start_date <= P.start_date  -- Maybe
    ORDER BY P1.start_date DESC
) PLookup
WHERE P.Customer = 'test'

You did not specify whether or not itemcode must be a match in the lookup logic, but I included that condition. Also, when looking up some latest value, that lookup is often relative to some reference date. If you want the latest price at or prior to the original row start_date, you can uncomment that condition above.
The P.trtype = '' condition is included in the lookup logic to exclude unnecessary lookups when the result is not needed.
Results:



itemcode
uom
price
start_date
FinalResult




ABC1234
EA
0
2024-01-15
29.57


X123456
CT
144.1
2024-05-15
144.1


BR23456
PC
0
2024-01-01
15.56


CX23456
PNL
0
2024-01-01
15.36



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

This solution uses joins instead of CASE THEN subqueries
WITH a as
(
  --This query returns all of the lvlholder records. 
  --Each blvl/itemcode combination is provided with a row numbers starting with the most recent.
  SELECT row_number() OVER (Partition by blvl,itemcode ORDER BY start_date desc) as rn,x.price,start_date,itemcode,blvl FROM pricing x WHERE  x.customer = 'lvlholder'
), t as
(
  --This query returns all of the lvlholder records where blvl=8.
  --Each itemcode is provided with a row number starting with the most recent.
  SELECT row_number() OVER (Partition by itemcode ORDER BY start_date desc) as rn, x.price,start_date,itemcode FROM pricing x WHERE x.blvl=8 AND customer = 'lvlholder'
)
SELECT p.[itemcode],
       p.[uom],
       p.[trtype], 
       p.[alvl],
       p.[blvl],
       CASE WHEN  p.[alvl]>0  THEN a.start_date
       WHEN p.[trtype] = '' THEN t.start_date
      ELSE p.[start_date] END as start_date,
  CASE 
  WHEN p.[trtype] = 'Quot' THEN p.[price]
  WHEN p.[alvl]>0  THEN a.price
  WHEN p.[trtype] = '' THEN t.price
  ELSE 0
  END AS LevelResult ,
  p.price
FROM pricing p
LEFT JOIN a ON a.itemcode=p.itemcode AND a.rn=1 AND a.blvl=p.alvl
LEFT JOIN t ON t.itemcode=p.itemcode AND t.rn=1
WHERE AND p.[Customer] ='test'  
      AND p.[itemcode] in ('ABC1234','X123456','BR23456','CX23456')
ORDER BY p.[start_date] desc

fiddle

Here is the query that fulfils your all three requirements, you can test it for values other than testcases it still works :
with cte as 
(
    select Blvl, max(start_date) as changed_date, Customer, itemcode
    from [pricing] 
    where Customer = 'lvlholder'
    group by Customer, itemcode, Blvl
)
select itemcode, uom, price, start_date, price as FinalResult
from [pricing] 
where [trtype] = 'Quot'

union

select a.itemcode, uom, price, changed_date as start_date, FinalResult
from [pricing] as a
left join cte on a.Alvl = cte.Blvl and a.itemcode = cte.itemcode
left join (select price as FinalResult, start_date, Blvl from [pricing]) as b
    on b.start_date = cte.changed_date and b.Blvl = cte.Blvl
where Alvl > 0

union

select a.itemcode, uom, price, changed_date as start_date, FinalResult
from [pricing] as a  
left join cte on a.itemcode = cte.itemcode 
left join (
    select price as FinalResult, start_date as new_date, itemcode from [pricing]
    where Blvl = 8 and Customer = 'lvlholder'
) as b
    on b.new_date = cte.changed_date and b.itemcode= a.itemcode
where a.Alvl = 0 and  a.trtype = '' and cte.Blvl = 8
 


Please add an explanation to your answer so OP can understand how it works.

Also, do you specifically want UNION over UNION ALL? Union is slower, but it does de-dup...
